# duplicated information to retrieve and assign to variable

Tags: bash

i have yet another question regarding bash.

in a text file, there is a set of information. the constant here is the "sys app" and the end "checker"

```
sys app /partition/app_webapps_80 {
load-balancing-mode least-connections-member
members {
    /partition/host-1:80 {
        address 10.20.20.200
    }
    /partition/host-2:80 {
        address 10.20.20.201
    }
}
checker /partition/tcp 
}
sys app /partition/app_webapps_8989 {
    members {
        /partition/host-1:8989 {
            address 10.20.20.200
        }
        /partition/host-2:8989 {
            address 10.20.20.201
        }
    }
    checker /partition/tcp 
}
```

what i did is to create a while loop, then i uses the following, however i get the address replicated the number of lines in the file.

```
line=1

while read do rs=$(sed -n '/sys app/,/checker/p' filename |grep -m $line "address" |tail -n 1) 
echo `$rs 
line=$[$line +1]`


done < filename
```

what should i go for, if i just want to match some information in between 2 string, then assign it to a variable that i can use for later?

appreciate any advise on this.

---

since under app_webapps_80 and app_webapps_8989
they have the same address 10.20.20.200 and address 10.20.20.201

the expected result is to run the loop.
and the loop will run to identify how many address there are between app_webapps_80 and the first checker

then assign the address 10.20.20.200 to a variable to use
and then assign address 10.20.20.201 to another variable to use

the loop will run again to identify the new app_webapps_8989 and the checker in that section
repeat what it does for the first set.

not sure if i make sense on this?

Comment: Could you post the expected result? Not in comments, [edit] the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing a range match, I think it will be easier to just read it from top to bottom.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

declare -A A=()

while read -r b c; do
    A[$b]=$c
done < <(awk '
    /^ *sys app /{b=substr($3,12)}
    /^ *address /{a[b]=sprintf("%s %s",a[b],$2)}
    END {
        for(c in a){print c a[c])}
    }' file)

# Let's iterate the assosiative array.
for d in ${!A[@]}; do
    set -- ${A[$d]}
    echo 1st   - $d: $1
    echo 2nd   - $d: $2
    echo All   - $d: $@
    echo Last  - $d: ${@:(-1)}
    echo Range - $d: ${@:1:2}
done
```